# Discord-JDA: How to get data about the user who joined the server?

Tags: java, javadoc, discord, discord-jda

How can I assign the User who has logged on to the server for the variable `User newUser`?

Part of my program:

`Main.java`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    try {
        JDA api = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken(token).build();
        api.addEventListener(new MyEventListener(api));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`MyEventListener.java`:

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    User newUser;
}
```

I read Javadoc and maybe I need to use [`GuildMemberJoinEvent`](http://home.dv8tion.net:8080/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/events/guild/member/GuildMemberJoinEvent.html). If this is what I need, then please help by giving a sample code how to use this function correctly for my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static User newUser;

@Override
public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {

    newUser = event.getUser();

}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {

    System.out.println(newUser.getName()); //...your code

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although this might answer the question, consider providing explanation where necessary and support with links to add more weight to your answer.

Comment: @RickM.This answer is enough to understand what he meant) It worked for me!